# Помогите с регулярным выражением, как захватить все строки блока?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Имеется такой текст.

```
==brigade - Бригада ==  
{| class="wikitable" style="width: 30%;"
| Поле
| Тип
| Описание
|-
| brigadier
| staffPersonnelNumber
| Бригадир
|-
| employees 
| employeCollection
| Сотрудники
|}
{| class="wikitable" style="width: 30%;"
| Атрибут
| Тип
| Описание
|-
| name
| string
| Наименование
|}

==employeCollection - Список сотрудников==
{| class="wikitable" style="width: 30%;"
| Поле
| Тип
| Описание
|-
| employe
| staffPersonnelNumber
| Сотрудник
|}
```

Пытаюсь захватить всю часть блока вики текста

Вот что у меня получилось.

```
(^==.*|}\s$)
```

Регулярка находит начало и конец каждого блока, а как захватить внутри весь блок не понимаю.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под словом `блок`?

Comment: блоки разделены пустой строкой, начинаются с == и заканчиваются |}

Comment: `(?m)^==[\s\S]*?(?=\n==|\z)`? https://regex101.com/r/48w1iB/1

Comment: Так, к слову - у вас минимум две ошибки. 1 - не забывайте, что `.` это `Любой символ, кроме новой строки`. 2 - `|` это служебный символ, который необходимо экранировать.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, эээ, нет, а с чего такой вопрос? Просто хотел помочь.

Comment: @icYFTL уже не актуально, а то было как в анекдоте про сотрудника мелкософта... Про двоих на воздушном шаре в тумане.